# Normalising time(minutes) related data with n other input variables(also dependant on time)

Tags: python, time-series, normalization

I am working on the GPS dataset of the football players with the energy expenditure being my output variable and other 15 variables being input/independent variables.

My objective is to forecast the energy progress of the players in the future matches if they are going to play for the full 90 minutes.

Say now I have 50 player's 150 matches data and the problem I am facing is that each player has played for different duration. Few players have played for 90 minutes in few of their matches and few have played only for 20-25 minutes in the match, so it is difficult for me to understand how to solve this problem.

```
sample data:
```

[image: Dataset]

The highlighted columns in the dataset are the columns I generated. Predicted is my prediction using Multi Linear Regression for each player, which has an accuracy of 98%. I tried to add energy/time * 90 mins, but the result is not efficient. I have done feature analysis and selection to filter the important 15 variables out of the 90 variables in the actual dataset.

```
Solution Needed:

Day     Player     Actual_Time player    Actual_Energy_Spent    Energy_if played_for_90mins
1        A            20                        15000              XXXXX

2        A            35                        16000              XXXXX

3        A            30                        14000              XXXXX
```

So, If I am able to predict that value for 90 minutes from the past matches using the 15 input variables, I would be able to forecast easily for the future matches as well. I am not sure of how to achieve this.

The other input variables such as distance are also dependant on the time_played.Can this be done using any statistical model or should I be using any system dynamics in resolving this problem.

[image: Variable importance]

Upon doing some research, I came to know about transfer function(Activation function) and there is a function in python SciPy to do it, but I haven't learned anything about it before and don't know if that would solve this problem. Being the only Data Analyst Intern with no seniors to work with or to guide, I am helpless. Any idea or suggestion or reference material for such solving this problem would be highly helpful and much appreciated.

thanks.